# How to call a dll C function in Delphi with the correct variable values?

Tags: c, delphi, dll

I've converted the following from "RFIDAPI.dll" C function to Delphi:

```
bool SAAT_YTagSelect( void *pHandle, 
                      unsigned char nOpEnable, 
                      unsigned char nMatchType, 
                      unsigned char *MatchData, 
                      unsigned char nLenth )
```

to

```pascal
function SAAT_YTagSelect( pHandle: Pointer; 
                          nOpEnable, 
                          nMatchType, 
                          MatchData, 
                          nLenth: PAnsichar): Boolean; stdcall;
```

I am trying to call the function and I am getting an Access Violation.  Apparently I am not assigning the correct value to the nOpEnable 1Byte variable.

Variable nOpEnable Buzzer or LED enable(1byte):

```
1: enable
0: disable
7   6   5   4   3   led buzzer
N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A 1   1
```

```pascal
procedure TForm5.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
  hp: Pointer;
  b: array[0..7] of AnsiChar;
begin
   b[0] := '1';
   b[1] := '1';
   b[2] := '0';
   b[3] := '0';
   b[4] := '0';
   b[5] := '0';
   b[6] := '0';
   b[7] := '0';
    if SAAT_YTagSelect(hp, b, '0x01', '84500080', '8') then
      StatusBar1.Panels[1].Text := 'Tag Selected';
end;
```

Comment: I believe you are asking for the c function:
bool SAAT_YTagSelect(void *pHandle,unsignedchar nOpEnable,unsigned char nMatchType,unsigned char *MatchData,unsigned char nLenth)

Comment: Did you read this yet: http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html

Comment: FWIW, `char *` is a pointer to an 8-bit character in C, so it can be translated as `PAnsiChar`. The `P` in that name stands for pointer. So you would normally translate `char` to `AnsiChar`, not to `PAnsiChar` (big difference!). But char can also by a byte, in C, especially if it is used as `unsigned char`. So the correct translation of `unsigned char` is, most of the time, `Byte`.

Comment: And you should really read the article David referred to. I am slowly beginning to see David's point about you not wanting to learn. In the olden days, they used to call such a person a [help vampire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem).

Comment: I did read the article, and yes trying to learn, eve though not a c# developer. For now just want to learn the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct translation of the function signature is:

```
function SAAT_YTagSelect(pHandle: Pointer; nOpEnable, nMatchType: Byte; MatchData: PByte; nLenth: Byte): Boolean; stdcall;
```

And the usage would look something like this:

```
var
  hp: Pointer;
  b: Byte;
  Data: PAnsiChar;
begin
   SAAT_TCPInit(hp, '192.168.0.238', 7086);
   SAAT_Open(hp);
   ...
   b := 1 or 2;
   data := '84500080';
   if SAAT_YTagSelect(hp, b, 1, PByte(data), 8) then
     StatusBar1.Panels[1].Text := 'Tag Selected';
   ...
   SAAT_Close(hp);
end;
```

I can't find any documentation for the `SAAT_YTagSelect()` function, so it is difficult to know for sure exactly what the `MatchData` parameter is expecting.  Considering that you have a habit of using strings for numeric parameters, it might even be something more like this:

```
var
  hp: Pointer;
  b: Byte;
  Data: array[0..7] of Byte;
begin
   SAAT_TCPInit(hp, '192.168.0.238', 7086);
   SAAT_Open(hp);
   ...
   b := 1 or 2;
   data[0] := 8;
   data[1] := 4;
   data[2] := 5;
   data[3] := 0;
   data[4] := 0;
   data[5] := 0;
   data[6] := 8;
   data[7] := 0;
   if SAAT_YTagSelect(hp, b, $01, @data[0], 8) then
     StatusBar1.Panels[1].Text := 'Tag Selected';
   ...
   SAAT_Close(hp);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Remy! It the call is not producing any errors, but its not activating the tag, I am wondering if the variable b which is the nOpEnable has to receive values to it's bit (a Byte has 8 bits right) There are two options buzzer and light that can be activated simultaneous, at the same time you can just activate the light not the buzzer. What would be the correct way to assign this values? 
Buzzer or LED enable(1byte):
1: enable
0:disable

Comment: Like I said, I cannot find the documentation for this particular function, so I don't know how the parameters should be set. A bit set makes sense, but whether it uses the low bits (`$1 or $2`, bitmask `$03`) or the high bits (`$80 or $7F`, bitmask `$C0`) is anyone's guess.

Comment: I could send you the documentation if you like!

Comment: @user734781: People try to help you, but it is bit too much to ask them to spend the best part of the day helping you. Try to find out a little bit yourself. ISTM you are trying to run before you can walk. Try something simpler first.

Answer (score 2):

The `unsigned char` parameters are 1-byte integral types, not strings... so they correspond to Delphi's `Byte` rather than `PAnsiChar`.  The numbers for each buzzer/LED are the bit positions to set in that byte, not a character position in a string.  So, the prototype should probably be:

```
function SAAT_YTagSelect(pHandle: Pointer; nOpEnable, nMatchType: Byte; MatchData: PByte; nLenth: Byte): Boolean; stdcall;
```

and the call should be something like:

```
procedure TForm5.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    hp: Pointer;
    b: Byte;
    data: PAnsiChar;
begin
    // set hp appropriately first
    b := 1 or 2; // Bitwise OR the values of each set bit
    data := '84500080';
    if SAAT_YTagSelect(hp, b, 1, PByte(data), 8) then
        StatusBar1.Panels[1].Text := 'Tag Selected';
end;
```

Also you haven't pointed `hp` at anything, which is likely a problem depending on what it's for.

Comment: Is it possible that the pointer is being assigned when the following function is called: function SAAT_Open(pHandle: Pointer): Boolean; stdcall;  ?

Comment: Thank you for your time!  I am still getting the same error!

Comment: @user734781 Not unless that `pHandle` points to the other `pHandle`... so probably not.

Comment: Yes, you need to use the same `Pointer` that you pass to `SAAT_Open()`.

Comment: Looks like the `pHandle` pointer is assigned through `SAAT_TCPInit()` or `SAAT_COMInit()`... after that, you pass it to each of the other functions.

Comment: `unsigned char*` is a byte array rather than a string. So that parameter should be `PByte`.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri! I am not getting any errors back, that is good singn, but it is not turnin the light or buzzer on,  Could you tell me how to set the valuesof each set bit?  "b := 1 or 2; // Bitwise OR the values of each set bit"

Comment: For bits 0-7, the values are 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128.. or in hex, $01, $02, $04, $08, $10, $20, $40, $80... just increasing powers of 2.  Just take the ones you need and `or` them together, or add them up ahead of time and just use the result.

Comment: David Hefferman, Then how do I assign values to that byte array and pass it on to the function?

Comment: By taking a pointer to the first byte. `SAAT_YTagSelect(..., @MyByteArray[0], ...);`. And if you have a Delphi supporting it, read up on the `{$POINTERMATH}` directive.

Comment: Adding to @Dmitri's last comment: I am pretty sure that there will be constants or enum values that have exactly these values. Use those, and simply `or` them together.